# How to get Cognito Identity Id in backend that is requested by AWS API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I use AWS Cognito authentication in my web application. I have a PHP backend with REST API. After user authentication I make requests to AWS API Gateway using [this library](https://github.com/kndt84/aws-api-gateway-client). API Gateway methods has HTTP integration type. They proxy HTTP requests to my PHP backend. How to get Cognito Identity Id in my PHP backend? I need to set a relation reference to the Cognito user in my backend.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

API Gateway makes the caller's identity id available in the [request context](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#context-variable-reference). Assuming you are using Cognito Identity Pool (federation) you are looking for this property: `$context.identity.cognitoIdentityId`.

You could configure API Gateway to send the value of the identity id in a new header to your backend. To achieve this you have to:

1. Open the integration request pane of the method configuration
2. Expand the HTTP headers section and click the "Add header" link
3. Give you header a name, such as `X-Cognito-Identity-Id`
4. In the "mapped from" field use the following expression: `context.identity.cognitoIdentityId`
5. Use the checkmark link on the right to save the configuration changes.

Re-deploy the API and your PHP backend should start receiving the additional header populated with the Cognito identity id from the original request.

Answer (score 1):

For those for who the answer provided by @stefano didn't work, you can replace the context variable `context.identity.cognitoIdentityId` with `context.authorizer.claims.sub`.

header name: `X-Cognito-User-Id` //or any name that you prefer

mapped from: `context.authorizer.claims.sub` // returns cognito user id.

Comment: User id is not identity id

Comment: Thank you.  This worked for getting the `App client id` from **Cognito User Pool**